# Batch Drag And Drop Problems

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

Recently I've been getting in to batch. I wanted to make a file that opens the file that you dragged on to it. But I can only seem to open a blank CMD window and or nothing at all. Here's my code.

```
@echo off
cd %dp1
start %1
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

just a missing tilde: `cd %~dp1`

Thanks, SomethinDark, I overlooked that. A bit expained:

a "dragged" file with spaces (in filename or path) will already be qouted. Which is good (no need to care about quotes).

`Start` takes the first quoted parameter as title, which is bad. I assume, your "blank CMD window"'s title is exactly your parameter?

Give `start` a dummy title to avoid that:

```
start "" %1
```

Best practice: **always*  use a title (blank or not) with `start`.

Comment: The `start` command should still be working, though... unless, of course, there are spaces in the path, then he'll have to use `"%~1"` or `start "" %1`.

Comment: I always like to use the /D option as well instead of using the CD command.